# Building PKGBUILD

Tags: packaging, arch-linux

I am building my first PKGBUILD.

The package I want to build is from a git repo. I've read the wiki guidelines but the CVS [page](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_CVS_%26_SVN_PKGBUILD_guidelines) is not very complete... When I makepkg, the procces seem to go straight, but in some point, it gets stuck. I don't know how to proceed.

```
# Maintainer: Tomas Sironi <sironitomas at gmail dot com>

pkgname=mutter-meego-git
pkgver=20101015
pkgrel=1
pkgdesc=""
arch=('i686' 'x86_64')
url="http://http://git.gitorious.org/meego-netbook-ux/mutter-meego/"
license=('GPL')
groups=()
depends=()
makedepends=('git')
optdepends=()
provides=('mutter-meego')
conflicts=('mutter-meego')

_gitroot="git://gitorious.org/meego-netbook-ux/mutter-meego.git"
_gitname="mutter-meego-git"

replaces=()
backup=()
options=()
install=
#~ source=($pkgname-$pkgver.tar.gz)
noextract=()
md5sums=() #generate with 'makepkg -g'

build() {
    export INCLUDE="/usr/include"

    msg "Connecting to the GIT server..."
    if [ -d ${_gitname}/.git ]; then
        cd ${_gitname}
        git pull
    else
        git clone ${_gitroot} ${_gitname}
        cd ${_gitname}
    fi

    ./configure.ac -prefix /usr \
                -libdir /usr/lib
    make || return 1
    make INSTALL_ROOT=$pkgdir install || return 1
}

package() {
  cd $srcdir/$pkgname-$pkgver
  make DESTDIR=$pkgdir install
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly `pkgdesc` which is short for *package description* should be filled out. Next, you don't need to have empty array's.

```
pkgname=mutter-meego-git
pkgver=20101015
pkgrel=1
pkgdesc="what mutter meego does"
arch=('i686' 'x86_64')
url="http://git.gitorious.org/meego-netbook-ux/mutter-meego/" # was not a correct uri
license=('GPL')
depends=() #seems to depend on some gnome stuff
makedepends=('git')
provides=('mutter-meego')
conflicts=('mutter-meego')

_gitroot="git://gitorious.org/meego-netbook-ux/mutter-meego.git"
_gitname="mutter-meego-git"

#~ source=($pkgname-$pkgver.tar.gz)
md5sums=() #generate with 'makepkg -g'

build() {
    export INCLUDE="/usr/include"

    msg "Connecting to the GIT server..."
    if [ -d ${_gitname}/.git ]; then
        cd ${_gitname}
        git pull
    else
        git clone ${_gitroot} ${_gitname}
        cd ${_gitname}
    fi

    ./configure.ac -prefix /usr \
                -libdir /usr/lib
    make || return 1
    make INSTALL_ROOT=$pkgdir install || return 1
}

package() {
  cd $srcdir/$pkgname-$pkgver
  make DESTDIR=$pkgdir install
}
```

remember the stuff in `build` is the same as if you were typing it out to build it. You have to run autogen.sh... and I couldn't do that due to some missing gnome dependency (I run KDE). You'll also notice that `./configure.ac` isn't executable... so how would you execute it? Figure out how to build it by hand and then put that in the build section of the PKGBUILD.